# Minimize variance of sum of random variables with respect to correlations

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X_1,\dots, X_n \sim N(0,1)$ with correlation matrix $\varrho_{i,j}$.
Denote $\Omega$ the set of feasible correlation matrices for the vector 
$(X_1,\dots, X_n)$.
My question:
Is there a way in evaluating

$$ \min_{(\displaystyle \varrho_{i,j}) \in \Omega} Var[X_1 + \dots + X_n]$$

In other words: Is there a straightforward way in determining the dependence 
structure given by pairwise correlations, which minimizes the variance of the sum?

Thanks for any replies, Daniel

Comment: Well, if $n$ is even you can have $X_{j+1}=X_j$ ($j$ even) so that $Var[X_1 + \cdots + X_n]=0$.

Comment: @leonbloy you may want to add a - sign.

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for your answer. I can't quite follow. Let's say $n=4$, then with $X_{i-1} = X_{i}$ for i even we have that $Var[X_1+...+X_4] = 4Var[X_2 + X_4]$. How do you get $Var[S_4] = 0$ ?

Comment: Okay now I get it. With the choice of $Corr[X_i, X_j] = -1$ for i, j even we get $Var[S_n] = 0$.

Comment: @mookid Yes, of course, my mistake

Comment: And what if $n$ is not even?